# Json Parsing issue iOS : missing "

Tags: iphone, ios, json, parsing

I got a big issue when trying to parse json data in xcode. I have actually tried with two different parser and it still returns me a wrong json. Could anyone help in that ?

The string  to parse (called jsonResp) is equal to :

```
{
   "error":false,
   "errorMessage":null,
   "debugMessage":null,
   "count":1,
   "list":"links",
   "data":[
      {
         "date":"Jeudi \u00e0 00:00:00",
         "type":"friend",
         "picture":"http://graph.facebook.com/22222222/picture? type=square",
         "name":"Etouda Gaudo",
         "ink_id":"1",
         "chat_id":"1",
         "count":"1",
         "last_message":"CoUcou"
      }
   ]
}
```

the string to parse is equal to :

```
NSData *jsonData = [jsonResp dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[CJSONDeserializer deserializer]  deserializeAsDictionary:jsonData error:&error];
NSLog(@"dictionary %@", dictionary);
```

and then I got the following result for the NSLog of dictionary :

```
dictionary {
count = 1;
data =     (
            {
        "chat_id" = 1;
        count = 1;
        date = "Jeudi \U00e0 00:00:00";
        "ink_id" = 1;
        "last_message" = CoUcou;
        name = "Test name";
        picture = "http://graph.facebook.com/22222222/picture?type=square";
        type = friend;
    }
);
debugMessage = "<null>";
error = 0;
errorMessage = "<null>";
list = links;
```

}

I can't figure out why the " are missing...
Does anyone have a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSLog is just a print representation for developers to view, it is the result of the `description` method being called on a class instance. Quotes are only added where the item might be ambitious without them such as a string with an embedded space.  To verify that the JSON was parsed correctly validate it with code.

Answer (score 2):

You are deserializing the JSON into an NSDictionary, which doesn't have to have quotes around it's property names, unlike JSON. Your parser is working correctly, but the NSLog of an NSDictionary won't show up exactly the same as the original JSON would.

Comment: Right.  The dump you get from using `description` on an NSArray or NSDictionary looks very close to JSON, but is not intended to mimic JSON syntax.  Nothing is wrong.